# copy random row if condition meets

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns one is user name and other one is decision now for each unique user i want 10% data.. for example if user name is Rohit and decision yes than 10% random of all rows where user decision was yes again for no 10% all the row of same user where decision is NO, This code is giving 10% data of unique name from column user only.

```
Sub Random10_EveryName()
    Randomize 'Initialize Random number seed

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Copy Sheet1 to new sheet
     Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    'Clear old data in Sheet 2
     Sheets(2).Cells.ClearContents

    'Determine Number of Rows in Sheet1 Column A
     numRows = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(Rows.Count, _
     "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Sort new sheet by Column E
     Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells.Sort _
     key1:=Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("O1:D" & numRows), _
     order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    'Initialize numNames & startRow variable
     numNames = 1
     startRow = 2

    'Loop through sorted names, count number of current Name
     For nameRows = startRow To numRows
     If Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(nameRows, "D") = _
     Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(nameRows + 1, "D") Then
     numNames = numNames + 1
     Else:
     endRow = startRow + numNames - 1

    'Generate Random row number within current Name Group
     nxtRnd = Int((endRow - startRow + 1) * _
     Rnd + startRow)

    'Copy row to Sheet2, Delete copied Name
     dstRow = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
     Sheets(Sheets.Count).Rows(nxtRnd).EntireRow.Copy _
     Destination:=Sheets(2).Cells(dstRow, 1)
     Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(nxtRnd, "D").ClearContents

    'Set Start Row for next Name Group, reset numNames variable
     startRow = endRow + 1
     numNames = 1
     End If
     Next

    'Sort new sheet by Column O
     Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells.Sort _
     key1:=Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("O1:E" & numRows), _
     order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    'Determine Number of Remaining Names in new sheet Column O
     numNamesleft = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(Rows.Count, _
     "E").End(xlUp).Row - 1

    'Determine 10% of total entries from Sheet1
     percRows = _
     WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((numRows - 1) * 0.2, 0)

    'Determine how many extra rows are needed to reach 10% of total
     unqNames = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, _
     "E").End(xlUp).Row - 1
     extRows = percRows - unqNames

    'Warn user if number of Unique Names exceeds 10% of Total Entires
     If extRows < 0 Then
     MsgBox "Number of Unique Names Exceeds 10% of Total Entries"
    'Delete new sheet
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     Sheets(Sheets.Count).Delete
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     Exit Sub
     End If

    'Extract Random entries from remaining names to reach 10%
    '
    'Allocate elements in Array
     ReDim MyRows(extRows)
    'Create Random numbers and fill array
     For nxtRow = 1 To extRows
    getNewRnd:
    'Generate Random row numbers within current Name Group
     nxtRnd = Int((numNamesleft - 2 + 1) * _
     Rnd + 2)
    'Loop through array, checking for Duplicates
     For chkRnd = 1 To nxtRow
    'Get new number if Duplicate is found
     If MyRows(chkRnd) = nxtRnd Then GoTo getNewRnd
     Next
    'Add element if Random number is unique
     MyRows(nxtRow) = nxtRnd
     Next

    'Loop through Array, copying rows to Sheet2
     For copyrow = 1 To extRows
     dstRow = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
     Sheets(Sheets.Count).Rows(MyRows(copyrow)).EntireRow.Copy _
     Destination:=Sheets(2).Cells(dstRow, 1)
     Next

    'Delete new sheet
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     Sheets(Sheets.Count).Delete
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try this (commented) code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim helpCol As Range, cell As Range
    Dim resultSht As Worksheet

    Set resultSht = GetOrCreateSheet("Results") '<--| change "Results" to your wanted name of the "output" sheet
    With Worksheets("Decisions") '<--| change "Decisions" to your actual data sheet
        With .Range("O1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference data from in columns "A:O" from row 1 down to last not empty row of column "A"
            Set helpCol = .Resize(, 1).Offset(, .Parent.UsedRange.Columns(.Parent.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column) '<-- set a "helper" column where to paste "names" and get unique ones only
            helpCol.Value = .Resize(, 1).Offset(, 3).Value '<--| paste "names" values from column "D" (i.e. offseted 3 columns from column "A") to "helper" column
            helpCol.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes '<-- get only unique "names" in "helper" column
            For Each cell In helpCol.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<-- loop through unique "names" in "helper" column
                .AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=cell.Value '<-- filter reference data on 4th column (i.e. column "D") with current "name"
                Filter2AndWriteRandom .Cells, 5, "YES", 0.1, resultSht '<-- filter again on 5th column (i.e. column "E") with "YES" and write random 10% in "output" sheet
                Filter2AndWriteRandom .Cells, 5, "NO", 0.1, resultSht '<-- filter again on 5th column (i.e. column "E") with "NO" and write random 10% in "output" sheet
            Next cell
        End With
        helpCol.ClearContents '<-- clear "helper" column
       .AutoFilterMode = False '<-- show all rows back
    End With
End Sub


Sub Filter2AndWriteRandom(rng As Range, fieldIndex As Long, criterium As String, perc As Double, resultSht As Worksheet)
    Dim nCells As Long, nPerc As Long, iArea As Long, iRow As Long, iArr As Long
    Dim sampleRows() As Long
    Dim filteredRows() As Long

    With rng '<-- reference passed range
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).AutoFilter field:=fieldIndex, Criteria1:=criterium '<-- filter on its passed 'filterIndex' column with passed 'criterium'
        nCells = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) - 1 '<-- count filtered cells, skipping header one
        If nCells > 0 Then '<-- if any cell filtered other than header one
            ReDim filteredRows(1 To nCells) '<-- resize the array that will collect the filtered rows row index
            With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<-- reference filtered data only
                For iArea = 1 To .Areas.Count '<-- loop through groups of cells into which data has been filtered down
                    For iRow = 1 To .Areas(iArea).Rows.Count '<-- loop through current 'Area' rows
                        iArr = iArr + 1 '<-- update filtered rows row index index
                        filteredRows(iArr) = .Areas(iArea).Rows(iRow).Row '<-- update filtered rows row index
                    Next iRow
                Next iArea
            End With
            nPerc = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(nCells * perc, 0) '<-- evaluate the number of rows to be randomly extracted
            sampleRows = GetRandomSample(nCells, nPerc) '<-- get the array with randomly chosen rows index
            For iRow = 1 To nPerc '<-- loop through number of rows to be randomly extracted
                resultSht.Cells(resultSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, .Columns.Count).Value = .Rows(filteredRows(sampleRows(iRow))).Value '<-- update "output" sheet
            Next iRow
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Function GetRandomSample(ByVal nNumbers As Long, nSamples As Long) As Long()
    Dim numbers() As Long
    Dim iSample As Long, i As Long
    ReDim rndNumbers(1 To nSamples) As Long

    numbers = GetNumbers(nNumbers)
    For iSample = 1 To nSamples
        i = Int((nNumbers * Rnd) + 1)
        rndNumbers(iSample) = numbers(i)
        numbers(i) = numbers(nNumbers)
        nNumbers = nNumbers - 1
    Next iSample
    GetRandomSample = rndNumbers
End Function

Function GetNumbers(nNumbers As Long) As Long()
    ReDim numbers(1 To nNumbers) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To nNumbers
        numbers(i) = i
    Next i
    GetNumbers = numbers
End Function

Function GetOrCreateSheet(shtName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetOrCreateSheet = Worksheets(shtName)
    If GetOrCreateSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set GetOrCreateSheet = Worksheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = shtName
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: getting subscript out of range for ReDim rndNumbers(1 To nSamples) As Long

Comment: most probably it's because `GetRandomSample()` received a zero as `nSamples` argument value, which on its turn should be the result of `nPerc = Int(nCells * perc)` when `nCells * perc` is less then 1. So I changed it with `nPerc = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(nCells * perc, 0)`, see edited code

Comment: Filter2AndWriteRandom .Cells, 5, "NO", 0.1, resultSht . can we change it as if any value instead of yes than take 10% ?

Comment: you are welcome. best thing is that you acted on given code and adapted to your needs with trial and error routine. this is what learning is mainly made of

Answer (score 0):

user3598756  I HAVE DONE something HERE CAN YOU MAKE ANY CHANGE SO THAT IF VALUE= NO DEFECT THAN COPY ONLY 10% FROM the row which has same user and decision.

```
Sub test()
Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, R As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, n As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Sheets(2).Cells.ClearContents
n = 1
lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
 For R = 2 To lr


 If Range("D" & R).Value = "gadrooa" And Range("E" & R).Value = "NO_DEFECT" Then
 Rows(R).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & n + 1)
 n = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


 End If
 Next R
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: this is a completely new issue, so make a new post for it! And see my edited post as to your _original_ question